# How to run a Parallel.ForEachAsync loop with NoBuffering?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, concurrency, producer-consumer, parallel.foreachasync

The synchronous [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) method has many overloads, and some of them allow to configure the parallel loop with the [`EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.enumerablepartitioneroptions) option:

> Create a partitioner that takes items from the source enumerable one at a time and does not use intermediate storage that can be accessed more efficiently by multiple threads. This option provides support for low latency (items will be processed as soon as they are available from the source) and provides partial support for dependencies between items (a thread cannot deadlock waiting for an item that the thread itself is responsible for processing).

There is no such option or overload for the asynchronous [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync). And this is a problem for me, because I want to use this method with a [`Channel<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1) as source, in a producer-consumer scenario as the consumer. In my scenario it is important that the consumer bites exactly what it can chew, and no more. I don't want the consumer pulling aggressively the `Channel<T>`, and then putting the pulled elements in its personal hidden buffer. I want the `Channel<T>` to be the only queue in the system, so that I can monitor it, and have accurate statistics about the elements that are waiting to be processed/consumed.

Until recently I was under the impression that the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` method is not buffering by design. But in order to be sure [I asked](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/72806) Microsoft on GitHub for a clarification. I got [feedback](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/72806#issuecomment-1194429993) very quickly, but not what I expected:

> It's an implementation detail. With `Parallel.ForEach`, the buffering is done to handle body delegates that might be really fast, and thus it's attempting to minimize / amortize the cost of taking the lock to access the shared enumerator. With `ForEachAsync`, it's expected that the body delegates will be at least a bit meatier, and thus it doesn't attempt to do such amortization. At least not today.

Being dependent on an implementation detail is highly undesirable. So I have to rethink my approach.

**My question is:** Is it possible to configure the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` API so that is has guaranteed `NoBuffering` behavior? If yes, how?

Clarification: I am not asking how to reinvent the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` from scratch. I am asking for some kind of thin wrapper around the existing `Parallel.ForEachAsync` API, that will "inject" the desirable `NoBuffering` behavior. Something like this:

```
public static Task ForEachAsync_NoBuffering<TSource>(
    IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source,
    ParallelOptions parallelOptions,
    Func<TSource, CancellationToken, ValueTask> body)
{
    // Some magic here
    return Parallel.ForEachAsync(source, parallelOptions, body);
}
```

The wrapper should behave exactly the same with the `Parallel.ForEachAsync` method on .NET 6.

---

**Update:** Here is the basic layout of my scenario:

```
class Processor
{
    private readonly Channel<Item> _channel;
    private readonly Task _consumer;

    public Processor()
    {
        _channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<Item>();
        _consumer = StartConsumer();
    }

    public int PendingItemsCount => _channel.Reader.Count;
    public Task Completion => _consumer;

    public void QueueItem(Item item) => _channel.Writer.TryWrite(item);

    private async Task StartConsumer()
    {
        ParallelOptions options = new() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 };
        await Parallel.ForEachAsync(_channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(), options, async (item, _) =>
        {
            // Call async API
            // Persist the response of the API in an RDBMS
        });
    }
}
```

There might be other tools available that could also be used for this purpose, but I prefer to use the smoking hot (.NET 6) `Parallel.ForEachAsync` API. This is the focus of this question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason that you _have_ to use `Channel<T>`? I don't disagree with the desire to eliminate the buffer, but I can't help but wonder if consumers of a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` might solve a lot of the complexity here, while preserving your ability to observe a single queue.

Comment: @DavidL the `Channel<T>` is actually built on top of a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/39d82c99b44db470f43fc12498c1aec082e5c6e2/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/UnboundedChannel.cs)). It adds waiting capabilities that the `ConcurrentQueue<T>` is lacking. For example a consumer can wait asynchronously until an item is available for consumption.

Comment: Consider implementing your own [partitioner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-dynamic-partitions) and use an override that supports [partitioner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-parallel-foreach-1(system-collections-concurrent-partitioner((-0))-system-threading-tasks-paralleloptions-system-action((-0))))

Comment: @MatJ AFAICS the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) method has no overload with `Partitioner` parameter.

Comment: Understood. But what is the use case for needing `Channel<T>` here? Is it the waiting capabilities? It just seems that your needs are at odds here, because you're always going to be dependent on some sort of implementation detail if you don't handle the parallelization yourself. Without some sort of additional overload/behavior added to `Parallel.ForEachAsync`, I'm not seeing a way to satisfy your ask, which is why I suggested a lower-level queueing implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I've found a way to implement the `ForEachAsync_NoBuffering` method. The idea is to feed the underlying `Parallel.ForEachAsync` loop with a fake infinite `IEnumerable<TSource>`, and do the actual enumeration of the `IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source` inside the `body`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Executes a for-each operation on an asynchronous sequence, in which iterations
/// may run in parallel. Items are taken from the source sequence one at a time,
/// and no intermediate storage is used.
/// </summary>
public static Task ForEachAsync_NoBuffering<TSource>(
    IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source,
    ParallelOptions parallelOptions,
    Func<TSource, CancellationToken, ValueTask> body)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(parallelOptions);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(body);
    bool completed = false;
    IEnumerable<TSource> Infinite()
    {
        while (!Volatile.Read(ref completed)) yield return default;
    }
    SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new(1, 1);
    IAsyncEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetAsyncEnumerator();
    return Parallel.ForEachAsync(Infinite(), parallelOptions, async (_, ct) =>
    {
        // Take the next item in the sequence, after acquiring an exclusive lock.
        TSource item;
        await semaphore.WaitAsync(); // Continue on captured context.
        try
        {
            if (completed) return;
            if (!(await enumerator.MoveNextAsync())) // Continue on captured context.
            {
                completed = true; return;
            }
            item = enumerator.Current;
        }
        finally { semaphore.Release(); }
        // Invoke the body with the item that was taken.
        await body(item, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }).ContinueWith(async t =>
    {
        // Dispose the enumerator.
        await enumerator.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        semaphore.Dispose();
        return t;
    }, default, TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach |
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default)
        .Unwrap().Unwrap();
}
```

The final [`ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith) is needed in order to dispose the enumerator, as well as the [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) that is used for serializing the operations on the enumerator. The advantage of the `ContinueWith` over a simpler `await` is that it propagates all the exceptions of the parallel loop.